# Opening different classes by Intent from the OnItemClick. According to the different names in the list

Tags: android, listview, click

hey all.. i have been looking at other questions to get help and answers without luck..
my problem is that i want to open different class from my listView. according to the specific name in the listView. . the names are in lv_arr[] .. 
If anybody can give a detailed answer i will be very thankfull and happy..
Im new in android and not the best in java :-(

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class StatusActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
    public ListView lv1;
    public String lv_arr[]= {"John", "Andrew","alex","alice","bob","bla bla"}; 


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.tabview);

        lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
        lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        new MenuInflater(getApplication())
                .inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return(super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu));
        }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.close:
                super.finish();
                break;
            case R.id.icontext:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(position == 0){
        //Intent w = new Intent (this, Seekbar.class);
        //startActivity(w);
            Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed the first item in the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You pressed all other items in the list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
   } 
}
```

Comment: does your onItemClick works? Do you see the different toast messages?

Comment: yes i see the diff toast msg.

Comment: (WarrenFaith) i see the diff toast msg according to the position..
but i want to open new classes according to the array in some how..

public String lv_arr[]= {"John", "Andrew","alex","alice","bob","bla bla"};

As you can see in my code i have tryied to open a new intent called seekbar.class then the app just craches..

Comment: Imagine that the naames in the array dont have same position each time..
so i have to check the array for "who" is "where" to start the diferent classes..

Comment: Than make a switch using `switch(position)` as you know the position of each name in the array, you know in which case you need to handle which name...

Answer (score 2):

try this....if you have doubts add comment.
**edited**:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tabview);

    lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
    lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));


  lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
    if(position==0){
            Intent i = new Intent(this, InfoActivity.class);
            startActivity(i); 
    } else if(position==1){
        start another activity here...
     }
   }
 });
}
```

hope it helps..

Comment: would be nice if you could format the code a bit... its messy

Comment: (Udaykiran).. i have try that the app just force to close

Comment: where the application get crashing..see the logcat

Answer (score 0):

well i think you want to know basically the flow of how it is possible.
If all the classes which should be opened are more likely the same with just text and image changes and same layout then you dont need to create separate class file for each and every item clicked.

Just create one class file and one xml file and on item click pass on the bundle to the class file which will just changes the content on different item clicks and will workk as a charm as with this flow you will have only one class file and one xml file for all the list items you have

If you dont want to keep the same layout then you can obviously make the some views gone, visible or invisible at runtime

Comment: its not really related to the question, right? He just wants to know how he can react differently depending on the item he clicked...

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
public String lv_class_names[]= {Activity1.class.getName(), Activity2.class.getName(), Activity3.class.getName(), .....};
```

In the `onItemClick` method write

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Class.forName(lv_class_name[position]));
startActivity(i);
```

for more details see [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)